# Trouble with variables in random number array

Tags: c, variables, random, multidimensional-array

Currently I am working on a program with a 2D array in creating a random number from 0 to 10000.  Things were going well until I was setting up my variables.  My code works out well until I set the character type for my variables.  Then the gcc compiler goes nuts. I've tried different character types and I still get an odd error.  Thanks for looking over my code so far.

```
32:     12. Terminate program.
33: 
34: CALL: ./a.out AFTER COMPILING WITH gcc (WITHOUT USING THE -o SWITCH)

40: */
41:
42: 

47: #include <stdio.h>
48: #include <stdlib.h>
49: #include <time.h>
50:
51:/*****************************************************************************/

int main ( void )
{  

72:    int random_nmb [4][6];
73:    int number, r, c;
74:
75:    srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));

       for (c=0; c<=3; c++)
       {
            for (r=0; r<=5; r++)
            {
            number = random( )%10001;
            random_nmb [r][c] = number;
            }
       }
}
```

Ok, here's the error code.

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
             from /usr/include/stdio.h:41,
             from ghp9.c:47:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:51: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or   
'__attribute__' before 'typedef'
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:74: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or  
'__attribute__' before '__int_least8_t'
```

Comment: Why don't you *include any error messages*? Are we supposed to understand exactly what you mean by "the gcc compiler goes nuts"?

Comment: Sorry @unwind, I just haven't seen anyone else add their error code on these type of websites.

Comment: are you sure you posted the entire source? there are no 47 lines in your code ...

Comment: What are the numbers? I hope they are not in your source code (are they supposed to be linenumbers? If yes where's the rest of the file? missing 43->46, 52->71 ...)

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Was it the 'B' on the apparent first line in the answer below?

Comment: @Fred yes, it was the 'B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fritzone Now I see why you wanted my whole code.  It was all the letter 'B'.  Thank you all for your help.  Below was my mistake.  Let's just place that problem that to sleep deprivation and inexperience.

```
B
/*
                 PROGRAM DESCRIPTIVE HEADER FOR GHP #9

SOURCE CODE FILE NAME: ghp9.c

PROGRAMMER NAME: XXXX

SHORT DESCRIPTION: This program will use an array to help pick 15 random
integers from numbers 0 to 10000.

ALGORITHM:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int random_nmb[4][6];
```

The above statement defines `random_nmb` to be an array of `4` objects each of type `int[6]`, i.e., an array of 6 integers. Therefore, the first index has to be in the range `[0, 3]` and second index in the range `[0, 5]`. Any other value of either indices will try to access memory out of bounds and invoke undefined behaviour.

You just need to change (in the inner `for` loop)

```
random_nmb[r][c] = number;
```

to

```
random_nmb[c][r] = number;
       //  ^  ^  indices swapped
```

Note the array indices have been swapped so that they do not go out of bound.

Comment: `char[6]`, and "characters"? Really?

Comment: @unwind Sorry. That was a typo. updated it. Thanks :)

Comment: @ajay Thanks... sadly I still have the same error message.